# How can I connect to PostgreSQL with Meteor from Objective-C (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, postgresql, meteor, subscription

I using ObjectiveDDP

https://github.com/boundsj/ObjectiveDDP

to connect to MongoDB on Meteor server by subscript collections and It worked, but Can I connect to PostgreSQL (Server using MongoDB and PostgreSQL together).

Thanks, sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

You can obviously access Postgre database on server using npm packages like this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg or using some ORM layer. But If you mean automatic sync PostgreSQL with clients using subscriptions with Meteor features like latency compensation - you can try this project https://github.com/meteor/postgres-packages - it is effort by MDG team itself to add full-stack support of PostgreSQL, but it is still in alpha